# Keras backpropagation vs self made backpropagation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, backpropagation

I have a CNN built with keras and my task is to run one step of the training data and get the gradients achieved by backpropagation and compare those to gradients that I calculate.

In order to do that, I need the weights and the loss function (the difference between expected and achieved outputs, whatever you call it), but I can't seem to get the actual value of the loss_function, all I get is a tensor, which I guess isn't evaluated.

```
Tensor("loss/mul:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
```

Those are the values and the type of what I get when I call model.total_loss. How do I actually get values from there, using one set of the training data?

EDIT 1: I've built the model, compiled it, and this is how I get the keras gradients for the sets in x_train.

```
gradients_tensor = K.gradients(model.output, model.trainable_weights)
sess = K.get_session()
evaluated_gradients = sess.run(gradients_tensor, feed_dict={model.input: x_train})
```

What do I have to call to get the loss function for the same input(s)?

EDIT 2:

```
# Build the model.
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(digits, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss = keras.losses.mean_squared_error,
              optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This is my model. This is essentially a school project, so I'm clearly new to keras and NN's in general. I really only have a theoretical understanding.

EDIT 3: Or if it's easier to just get the outputs of running the NN once on an input, that would be exactly the same to me.

EDIT 4: I just ended up using model.predict to get the output values and I can use those to calculate the losses myself. Thanks for the help.

Comment: In tensorflow you just build the graph. At the very end you do a session.run(feed_dict=a) and a is dictionary to configure your placeholder. I can only provide more help if you provide me with an [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: Are my edits helpful?

Comment: After you calculated your weights, you can calculate the loss function once again at the end of the graph and do `sess.run(loss_fun, feed_dict=feed_dict)`. That will return the loss function

Comment: `loss = sess.run(model.total_loss, feed_dict={model.input: x_train})` - gives me an error, I'm probably being such an idiot. Is "total_loss" not what I'm looking for? Or is that not the dict I should be feeding it? The error is: `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'dense_2_sample_weights' with dtype float and shape [?]
  [[Node: dense_2_sample_weights = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]`

Comment: As it is said, you have configured your `dense_2_sample_weights` as placeholder and not as `tf.Variable(tf.zeros([size_x, size_y]))` as you should. If something is a placeholder you must provide a value in `feed_dict`. The graph can't run through without the placeholder value

Comment: I appreciate the help, I'm new to keras and actually implementing NN's. Edit 2 is my model.

Comment: Also, I should not be using model.total_loss, that is just the sum of the list of losses for each output layer neuron, isn't it?